# Primefaces upload, how to only allow one upload in advance mode

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I am wondering if it possible, by using the primefaces upload in advance mode to limit the user uploading one file only, currently i have :

```
 <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"
                                  mode="advanced" 
                                  multiple="false" 
                                  update="messages"
                                  sizeLimit="100000000" 
                                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|doc|docx|txt|pdf)$/"
                                  auto="false"/>


                    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
```

as you can see i have muliple ="false" but a user is still able to upload multiple files, any tips ?

EDIT :

```
                <p:fileUpload widgetVar="upload" fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"
                              mode="advanced" 
                              multiple="false" 
                              update="messages"
                              label="Select File"
                              sizeLimit="100000000" 
                              allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|doc|docx|txt|pdf|html)$/"
                              auto="false"/>


                <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
```

have added the widgetVar above

and in my js

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        function Naviagtion()
        {
            //alert("Sent to the printing holding queue, you may close this app now, your work will still print out ");
            window.setTimeout(afterDelay, 500);
            location.href = 'FilesUploaded.xhtml';

        }

        upload.buttonBar.find('input[type=file]').change(function() {
            if (this.value) {
                var files = upload.uploadContent.find('.files tr');

                if (files.length > 1) {
                    files.get(0).remove();
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

but i am still able to multi upload, am i going about this in the right direction

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `multiple="false"` only tells the webbrowser to disable multiple file selection in the browser-specific *Browse* dialog. However, it indeed doesn't prevent the enduser from clicking multiple times on the *Choose* button of the PrimeFaces file upload section to browse and add a single file multiple times.

Your best bet is to bring in some JS/jQuery to remove all previously selected files when a new file is selected. Provided that you have given your `<p:fileUpload>` a `widgetVar="upload"`, then this should do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    upload.buttonBar.find('input[type=file]').change(function() {
        if (this.value) {
            var files = upload.uploadContent.find('.files tr');

            if (files.length > 1) {
                files.get(0).remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Works for me on PrimeFaces 3.5.

Comment: Could you take a look at my edit, am i going about this the right way ? Thanks

Comment: The variable name `upload` in the JS code example is specified by the component's `widgetVar` attribute. In your particular case, you gave it the name `widgetVar`, so you should replace `upload` in the JS code example by `widgetVar` (and pay attention to browser's builtin JS console, you'd have noticed a JS syntax error something like "reference error: widgetVar is not defined").

Comment: thank you, i have changed the name to `upload` and in the browser console i have `Uncaught ReferenceError: upload is not defined index.xhtml:76
(anonymous function)`

Comment: As said, you need to initialize it during document ready. If you aren't already using it, put this code in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`. I updated the answer.

Comment: I think files.get(0).remove() should be $(files.get(0)).remove();

Comment: this solution didn't work for me in a project that uses Primefaces 5.1.

Comment: @yannicuLar: Q&A was written at date PF 3.5 was mainstream. Apparently PF 5.x changed HTML/JS output as compared to 3.5, then the answer needs to be altered on that.

Comment: @BalusC I don't think that this affects your answer (btw I upvoted). Still, I think it was worth mentioning. By the way, I think that the `fileLimit` attribute is not new: it was removed in version 3.4 and re-implemented for v.4.0 https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3618

Answer (score 13):

Although better behavior to solve it should be as @BalusC suggested, but in primefaces 4.0 I am seeing the attribute

```
fileLimit="1"
```

which you can set to 1 to disallow multiple file additions using "Choose" button. When user adds more file then it simply says

> "Maximum number of files exceeded"

Comment: good catch. This the right solution for Primefaces version of 4 or above.

Answer (score 0):

If you have file limit set to 1 and some error happens while file is loading - you have to refresh the page to get file upload work again. If you don't refresh the page you get out of limit error message.

I used solution with JS, like in accepted answer,but have to change selectors, because wigetWar did not work for me.

In my view i have :

```
<p:fileUpload id="objectUpload"... />
```

In my portlet theme, table with files has a css class of "ui-fileupload-files".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div[id*='objectUpload']").find('input[type=file]').change(function() {

    if (this.value) {
        var files = $("div[id*='objectUpload']").find('.uifileupload-files tr');        
        if (files.length > 1) {     
            files.get(0).remove();
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Hope it helps.I used PrimeFaces 6.0