# Upload one file in primefaces uploadFile

Tags: javascript, jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I have problem trying to upload files in Primefaces because I can select more than one file in the dialog, but I want to appear one file in the list.

I found in this thread how to do it, but didn´t works with me

[Primefaces upload, how to only allow one upload in advance mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881131/primefaces-upload-how-to-only-allow-one-upload-in-advance-mode)

I have 4 fileuploads dialogs.

One example of

```
<p:fileUpload
        fileUploadListener="#{atendenteBean.executarUpload}"
        mode="advanced"
        multiple="false"
        sizeLimit="3000000"
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
        cancelLabel="#{lbl['BOTAO.CANCELAR']}"
        uploadLabel="#{lbl['BOTAO.ENVIAR']}"
        label="#{lbl['BOTAO.SELECIONAR']}"
        widgetVar="cpf"
    />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        cpf.buttonBar.find('input[type=file]').change(function() {
            if (this.value) {
                var files = cpf.uploadContent.find('.files tr');

                if (files.length > 1) {
                    files.get(0).remove();
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

In console of chrome is getting the same erros as user `Uncaught ReferenceError: cpf is not defined` so whats the problem?

I put my js code in the top of the page

Comment: @BalusC it´s a real code, how I said, I have 4 dialogs in the page, so I got one and the function from other, I don´t want to paste all the code because it will be so long....

Comment: This carelessness in preparing for getting answers is however often not appreciated as it often indicates that you couldn't be bothered about the quality of your own input nor on those of the answers. Be careful :)

Comment: @BalusC you are right, thanks, now I need to someone to help me!

Comment: `cpf` as an id is not in use anywhere else on the page? Also did you try this across multiple browsers?

Comment: @kolossus I´m gonna try to change this variable and I need to use in every browser.

Comment: @kolossus I changed the name of variable and didn´t worked